# Как правильно: миллионоголосый или миллионноголосый

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

Здравствуйте!
Как правильно:
"миллионоголосый" или "миллионноголосый"?

Answer (score 6):

Миллион голосов - миллионоголосый, способ образования - суффиксальное сложение основ, суффикс нулевой. Откуда перед соединительной гласной О возьмется удвоение Н?  Сравнить: сто миллионов - стомиллионный (сто + миллионный, чистое сложение.

ОТВЕТ 2: "Откуда-то издалека сквозь безмолвие пустыни донесся миллионоголосый крик". Это крик миллиона голосов. А миллионный голос - это миллионный по счету голос, порядковое числительное, сравнить: миллионный покупатель.Давайте тогда говорить: тысячноголосый, а то в одном случае основа существительного, а в другом - основа прилагательного.

ОТВЕТ 3. Почему предлагается писать "миллионноголосый"? Вот их ответ: это начальная часть сложных слов, вносящая значение: исчисляемый миллионами (миллионноголосый, миллионнолетний и т.п.). Но извините, господа! Все-таки исчисляется-то МИЛЛИОНАМИ, а не МИЛЛИОННАМИ! А далее следует образование сложного слова по схеме того же Лопатина. Так что теперь, грамматику реформируем? От какого числа указ?
В 2001 ГОДУ Лопатину запретили "упрощение" русской орфографии в угоду малограмотному населению, потому что такое упрощение затрагивает грамматические основы языка. Но эти люди не успокоились, и у нас идет ползучая реформа. Хорош неологизм! Кажется, неологизмами мы называем новые слова, а не "покалеченные" старые. Нужно абсолютно не понимать и не любить русский язык, чтобы вводить такие изменения, и нужно абсолютно раболепствовать перед "начальством", чтобы их одобрять.

ОТВЕТ 4. Если грамматика - это наука, то она должна быть точной. Словообразование - часть грамматики, и все схемы образования слов там обозначены. Нельзя для каждого слова изобретать собственный вариант образования. Если вы хотите писать миллионноголосый, то первая основа должна быть основой прилагательного "миллионный", а это порядковое числительное. Наше письмо грамматическое (не фонетическое) - непонятно, о какой фонетике вы говорите. Мы смотрим запись слова, и по нему считываем смысл. И что мы считаем с вашего "миллионноголосого"? То, что это миллионный голос, а не миллион голосов. Неужели это так трудно понять, или просто не хочется понять?

Comment: Справедливо!  
http://orthography.academic.ru/15218/миллионоголосый  
*Тысячеголосый*

Comment: Нам говорят : положено писать два Н! Что же нам поделать с **маяковским написанием**?

>А если
      в партию
              сгрудились малые –
сдайся, враг,
             замри
                  и ляг!
Партия –
        рука миллионопалая,
сжатая
      в один
            громящий кулак.  
............  

 >Класс миллионоглавый
напрягает глаз –
                себя понять.

Ни Ушаков, ни Ожегов/Шведова не фиксируют словоформы **миллионно-**, ее не существует для них. Чего же ради последующие словаристы самовольно изменяют неологизм В.В.??

Comment: Выходит, теперь есть, Ожегов устарел,50 лет прошло, язык меняется:
http://edudic.ru/efr/49973/ Неологизмы становятся активным запасом. Капрон тоже был неологизмом,а теперь скоро будет устаревшим.

Comment: Капрон изменил написание? Или фильдеперсовые чулки...  
> И. Грекова. Дамский мастер (1963)  …Сколько я себя помню, всегда в дефиците были какие-нибудь чулки. Когда-то ― фильдекосовые, фильдеперсовые. Потом ― капрон.

Comment: Словаристы самовольно изменяют написание, несолидно!  
>Е. И. Замятин. Мы (1920) В такт сыпались тысячи ног, миллиононогий левиафан, колыхаясь, плыл мимо  
>Е.Велтистов. Глоток солнца (1967) Но сейчас, сидя за праздничным столом, я был далеко от этих людей; я был в пустом космосе, один среди миллионоглазых звезд, и еще дальше ― на холодной пустынной планете под холодным красным солнцем.  
>В.Конецкий. На околонаучной параболе (Путешествие в Академгородок). Повесть (1978) Когда человек лжет, он нарушает **миллионолетний закон** живой природы.

На тексты надо опираться, господа словаристы...

Answer (score 2):

миллионноголосый

Если не верите, то: [миллионноголосый](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?ab=x&az=x&bts=x&help=1&lop=x&lv=x&pe=x&sin=x&word=%EC%E8%EB%EB%E8%EE%ED*&zar=x)

Comment: Вот вам и авторитетный словарь((((
А не новация ли это лопатинская?
Хотя у меня тоже второе Н просится.

Comment: Точно. Лопатин. Он считает "милионно" не сложением "милион+о+что-то там", а самостоятельной начальной формой как "одно", "тысяче" и наверное "миллиардно..."  
До него так не считали.

Comment: Да, это Лопатин. Но его поддерживает и Ефремова, они относятся к одной школе. Они производят от другого словосочетания - миллионный голос, теперь по этой схеме пишут и другие слова:миллионный доллар - миллионнодолларовый. Я не могу сказать, что не принимаю это,тоже хочется произнести с двумя-НН-, хотя раньше писала с одной, в словаре трудностей тоже одна,но ведь теперь мы пишем по Лопатину? Остальное - не норма?

Comment: Мы НЕ пишем по Лопатину. 
Если есть два словаря более или менее актуальных и одинаково авторитетных в соответствующей области, то мы признаем верными оба написания. Я другого подхода не вижу.
Ну тут я скорее напишу именно по Лопатину. Фонетически ближе, что ли.
Кстати, я думаю, от производит не от числительного "миллионный", а от прилагательного "принадлежащий миллионам". Думаю, это логично.

Answer (score 0):

Ну и что мы спорим?

Орфографический словарь: миллионноголосый

Comment: Желательно не просто учить орфографический словарь наизусть, но и объяснить форму написания слова и причины ее недавнего изменения. Может быть, вы объясните способы образования сложных  слов "тысячеголосый - миллионноголосый", сравнив их между собой?

Comment: Милая София, это на Грамоте.ру ссылка на орфографический словарь.
Не могу не доверять уважаемому порталу.

Мне такое написание ближе, нежели с одним "н".
Но Ваше объяснение прочла с большим интересом.

Comment: Татьяна, и я постоянно заглядываю на Грамоту.ру, потому что это ОФИЦИАЛЬНЫЙ портал. И я не советую писать "миллионоголосый", потому что это сочтут за ошибку. Но это нарушение морфологического принципа орографии и очень нехороший прецедент в части правил, регулирующих написание сложных слов.

Comment: София, я прислушалась к Вам, как делаю это всегда. 
С огромным удовольствием читаю Ваши развёрнутые комментарии. 
Жаль, что нет такого общественного движения, которое бы объединило всех неравнодушных к родному языку.

Над "злосчастным" словом буду думать. 

И у меня аналогичная проблема. 
К примеру, проверяю тексты, где составной союз в начале предложения, а начальство упорно ставит запятую, разделяя его на две части.
Или пишу уже в сотый раз в "Комсомолку", чтоб не путали людей и писали млн и млрд без точки, и никакой реакции!

Answer (score 0):

> : миллионноголосый

Оттуда же: миллионно... -первая часть сложных слов (в знач. исчисляемый миллионами), пишется слитно

миллионноголосый