# Лопатин и Розенталь - в чём отличие?

Tags: грамматика, правила

Часто, как начинается лингвистический спор, один яростно машет справочником Лопатина, другой - справочником Розенталя. Настолько отличаются мнения учёных? В чём разница между ними? Объясните, пожалуйста, кто-нибудь доходчиво.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если Лопатин - это словарь на Грамоте, то я пропасть ошибок у него обнаруживаю (если он не перенёс в свой труд скопированное толкование с примерами).

Пожалуйста, то, что помню как потрясшее:

**[Она умна, мила, наконец хорошо воспитанна.](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86&all=x)**

Две ошибки на короткое предложение - это немножко множко.

Ога, то не Лопатин, а  Кузнецов; значит, оба хороши.

Цитата:

> «Как только появилась школа Лопатина, какой-то худо-бедно
>   существовавший порядок в правописании вообще разрушили, развели
>   какую-то дурацкую полемику. Русский язык и так настолько сложен, а тут
>   пытаются установить полный хаос.
>
> По крайней мере, правила Розенталя не в пример Лопатину четкие и
>   ясные. И лично я буду их придерживаться, несмотря ни на что. Так же
>   думают все мои коллеги: корректоры, редакторы текстов, филологи - все,
>   с кем я говорила на эту тему. Так что мы протестуем против этой
>   реформы словом и действием и не допустим ее».
>
> ---

Понятно, что на основе правил 2000 года должна была появиться новая версия руководства для издательских работников вроде популярного «Розенталя», и в итоге новое издание «Справочника по правописанию и литературной правке» (2003) уже содержит ряд изменений «по Лопатину», например в употреблении прописных букв...

В двух рассмотренных (см. ИСТОЧНИК) неудачных попытках реформ

> причины «поражения» не сводятся ни к слабостям их лингвистической
>   подготовки, ни к прямому противодействию государственных структур.
>   Несмотря на общее происхождение из идей реформаторов начала ХХ века,
>   они развивали две разные логики упорядочивания правописания:
>   *радикальная 1964 года* более последовательно воплощала фонематический принцип, а *компромиссная 2000 года* ориентировалась на уже
>   устоявшиеся написания и «подправления» столь же компромиссного свода
>   1956 года.
>
> Работа орфóграфов протекает между двумя полюсами: системных и текущих
>   изменений - в словарном составе языка и в медленно меняющейся
>   письменной практике. Орфографам приходится даже вне реформ быть
>   кодификаторами - упорядочивать вновь поступающий материал: закреплять
>   написание новых слов, устанавливать дефисное или слитное написание,
>   определять прописные буквы, выбирать транскрипционный или
>   транслитерационный принцип для заимствованных слов и так далее.
>
> В этом смысле отсутствие изменений в переизданиях орфографического
>   словаря между 1974-м и 1991 годами создало, с одной стороны, ощущение
>   стабильности, что явилось невыгодным фоном для проекта 2000 года; а с
>   другой стороны, вызвало то напряжение, которое этот проект и должен
>   был разрешить: сколько за эти годы появилось новых слов, которые нужно
>   было отразить, в том числе слов со спорным написанием! И все же
>   критической массой для успешной реализации проекта это не стало.

**[источник](http://www.intelros.ru/readroom/nz/nz_71/6973-istoriya-s-orfografiej-neudavshiesya-reformy-russkogo-pravopisaniya-vtoroj-poloviny-xx-veka.html)**

---

[Реформа Лопатина](http://xn--80afqvalc3ae5i.xn--c1avg/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_1956_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0_.D0.9B.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.B0)

> В 2000 году Орфографическая комиссия издала орфографический словарь на
>   160 000 слов, в основном отражающий текущие написания. В 2006 году
>   комиссия подготовила свод новых правил, вышедший в 2007 году
>   ограниченным тиражом. Правила практически не отступают от словаря
>   Лопатина (единственное найденное различие - "вот-те раз"). Правила
>   более полны, чем правила 1956 года, из-за чего и более сложны. В
>   частности, правила написания о/ё после шипящих занимают 6 страниц, а
>   правила написания двойного н - 9 страниц. Представители МГУ выступили
>   с некоторой критикой новых правил.
>
> Важно заметить, что комиссия отказалась от многих своих идей по
>   реформе, в том числе такой удачной, как написание ъ между частями
>   сложносокращённого слова перед е,ё,ю,я (инъяз вместо иняз). За отменой
>   реформы стоит Людмила Путина.
>
> Замеченные явные изменения в правилах (комиссия сама не опубликовала
>   список изменений):
>
> 1. полосануть (свод 2007 59/, словарь Лопатина) вместо полосонуть (свод 1956, БОШ)
> 2. разыскной (свод 2007 54/, словарь Лопатина) вместо розыскной (БОШ)
> 3. зарянка (свод 2007 43/, словарь Лопатина) вместо зорянка (БОШ)
> 4. цыркать (свод 2007 28/) - дополнение к списку слов на цы-
> 5. о кИе (и даже о киЕ) и т.п. (свод 2007 79/, словарь Лопатина) - против о кии (свод 1956)
> 6. тундреный (свод 2007 61/) (нет в БОШ) - новое исключение для двойных н
> 7. давно не метёный пол (с одним н)
> 8. форсмажор вместо форс-мажор, хотя терц-мажор оставлено, а ноты и лады пишутся через дефис: соль-диез, ми-бемоль, до-мажор, ля-минор и
>      т.п.
> 9. вот-те раз (свод 2007 151/; рядом чёрт-те что) вместо вот те раз (словарь Лопатина 2000).
> 10. узаконено дублирование дефиса при переносе (т.е. дефис есть в конце строки и в начале следующей), что ранее запрещалось по 1956:123.
>       Интересно, что такой перенос есть уже в авторском предисловии к 4-му
>       изданию толкового словаря Ожегова (1960) - как минимум в той его
>       версии, которая приведена в 9-м издании (1972).

---

БОШ - словарь Бархударова--Ожегова--Шапиро.

Comment: Галина, а что означают цифры после года?

Comment: Серж, мне было трудно копировать и редактировать - я и так постаралась убрать избыточное; посмотри по ссылке - может, там (в источнике) что-то прояснится?

Comment: Да, спасибо, я посмотрю.

Comment: Galina Avanesova, а каких ошибках вы говорите?

Comment: «Как только появилась школа Лопатина, какой-то худо-бедно существовавший порядок в правописании вообще разрушили, развели какую-то дурацкую полемику. Русский язык и так настолько сложен, а тут пытаются установить полный хаос».

Comment: Форс-мажор и сейчас пишется через дефис.Я имел в виду ваш пример. О каких ошибках там идет речь?

Comment: Сержик, дорогой! Я в ауте! В словаре: "Она умна, мила, наконец хорошо воспитанна"; а надо бы: "Она умна, мила, наконец, хорошо воспитана", - *наконец* при перечислении (того-сего-пятого-десятого) обособляется; одно *н* в "воспитана" обусловлено наречием "хорошо", превращающим краткое прилагательное в причастие.

Comment: Галина, я им писал по поводу ошибок, но они, увы, молчат. Вот пример:  ***ВИДНО. I. нареч., в функц. сказ***. Можно видеть, рассмотреть. Дом ***виден*** издалека. Есть и другие ошибки, но уже не помню.

Answer (score 4):

**Я лично рассматриваю редакцию  Лопатина как попытку максимально упростить правописание, чтобы народ хотя бы немного грамотнее стал.**

Только вот грамотнее он не станет. Наш орфография и пунктуация **основана на грамматике (то есть на порядке)**, и, хотя в Правилах 1956 года об этом прямо не говорится, эта основа просматривается во всех работах Розенталя. Поэтому они логичны и понятны, да вот кому-то они показались сложными.

**И теперь вместо будто бы "сложной гармонии"  нам предлагают "простую путаницу",** в которой еще сложнее разобраться и которую надо просто зубрить (а некоторым этот метод нравится: учи и ни о чем не думай, за тебя обо всем уже подумали).

Особенно я не могу принять лопатинское "миллионноголосый", но написание слова сейчас, кажется, исправили, см. дискуссию: [Как правильно: миллионоголосый или миллионноголосый](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/26831/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%B9).

**Другой вопрос** – это дефисное (очень простое!) написание всех нарицательных существительных (красавица-невеста и невеста-красавица).

Comment: "Наш орфография и пунктуация основана на грамматике (то есть на порядке)" — это как вообще?

Comment: Грамматика - это упорядоченный строй языка, и грамматический принцип является основным для правописания, поэтому произвольные, непродуманные изменения в орфографии могут отрицательно повлиять на всю систему правописания.

Comment: @Sibylla, с некоторыми написаниями можно, конечно, не соглашаться. Но некоторые изменения, на мой взгляд, нормальны.

Comment: Серж, я  написала, что мне очень не нравится у Лопатина (это те темы, которые касаются грамматики, ну не должна орфография управлять грамматикой). А  вот какое изменение  Вам особенно НРАВИТСЯ, то есть Вы считаете его принципиально  важным и полезным для русского письма?

Comment: Могу лишь перечислить некоторые на мой взгляд удачные изменения. Разысканной, зарянка,слитное написании сложных слов с начальными компонентами аудио-, видео.

Comment: Предлагалось писать: перекатиполе вместо перекати- поле. хотя такое написание отклонили, но, на мой взгляд, было бы логично писать слитно.

Comment: Серж, мне кажется, что не зря упомянуты 6 страниц правила на одно и 9 на другое... Неграмотного это ещё больше запутает, а у грамотного старые написания слов от зубов отскакивают!

Comment: Поэтому многие изменения не были одобрены.

Comment: *Наша орфография и пунктуация основана на грамматике (то есть на порядке)*. Ужас какой. Умствование до добра не доводит.