# Лопатин или Розенталь? Кому верить?

Tags: грамматика, правила

У меня к вам всем вопрос. Думаю, вы знаете Розенталя и Лопатина. Но вот кому из них доверять в орфографии и пунктуации? Потому что Лопатина корень сид- и сед- относятся к чередующимся, а у Розенталя - нет. Да и не только корни, там много отклонений от поставленных правил Розенталем. И уже начинается настоящая путаница. А русский язык хочется знать лучше, но на кого опираться?  Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Повтор вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431277/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B8-%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: @Jasmin настоятельно прошу вас указывать дублеты вопросов через кнопку тревоги: тревога -- дубликат -- можно вставить ссылку, а можно использовать строку как интерфейс поиска -- голосовать за закрытие!

Comment: Никто не знает (в настоящем времени) Розенталя (светлая ему память), так как его уже нет с нами. Вряд ли кто-то из авторов ответов знает Лопатина (дай ему бог здоровья). А вот с их трудами многие знакомы.

Comment: Нельзя так писать: "поставленных правил Розенталем", корректно: "правил, установленных Розенталем". В этом, думаю, можно опереться на любого из двух авторов.

Comment: Это не то чтобы дуплет вопроса, а повторение темы. Я не предлагаю вопрос закрыть: там есть о чем поговорить, не всё еще сказано, просто предварительно нужно ознакомиться с уже полученными ответами.

Answer (score 2):

Я, к примеру, обычно обращаюсь к Розенталю, а справочник Лопатина использую, если есть желание найти какие-то современные аспекты в изложении правил.

К примеру, Лопатин **добавил информацию о чередующихся корнях,** в частности о корне СИД/СЕД.

Собственного говоря, у нас нет четкого определения для этой темы. Так, в паре загореть/загорать мы видим явное чередование гласных в корне с **одним значением.** А вот корень МАК/МОЧ имеет **разные оттенки значений,** но Розенталь разбирает этот корень в данной теме.

С другой стороны,  **корень СИД/СЕД также имеет разные оттенки значений:** находиться в положении сидя или принять это положение, с учетом исключений.

**Поэтому  можно извлечь пользу  из обоих источников и при этом не дать себя запутать,** но подходить к их использованию нужно разумно, а не чисто формально.